# qtimer and opencv running slow

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, computer-vision, video-processing

I'm writing a code that uses QTimer to trigger calls to opencv videoCapture to read video frames. I usually read large chunks of videos so, wondering is there any other way to accelerate the process.

here a snapshot of my code that uses QTimer :

```
timer = new  QTimer();
timer->setTimerType(Qt::PreciseTimer);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(read_shape_params()));

//in a loop stop timer and setup the next video stream then start

void next(){

  timer->stop();

   stream = new video_stream_reader();
   stream->setColorGray(grayImage);
   stream->set_begin_end(begin_at,end_at);
   stream->open(video_base_path+video_path);

   timer->start(0);
}

void shape_param_finder::read_shape_params(){
   Mat frame;
   frame = stream->read_frame();
}

Mat video_stream_reader::read_frame(){
   Mat frame;
   bool bSuccess = capture->read(frame);
   return frame;

}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve, is the timer running too slow?

Comment: Yes , exactly. QTimer  is really slow

Comment: It could be because your are creating a new timer object. Just create one before the loop

Comment: @RiyadhMohammed How did  you evaluate the speed of QTimer?

Comment: @UmNyobe  Lets say the video length is 5 minutes. The time my software take to process all frames is more than 5 minutes.

Comment: Then it is not Qtimer. How do you make sure you dont read the same frame twice?

Comment: @GPPK I use only one QTimer object for the whole loop

Comment: @UmNyobe I use a frame counter in the stream object to move to the next frame. This works fine because I also, that by the total number of frames I have processed. I also, have a preview option which allows me to see the frames I read. It seems a little slower than watching the original video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has little to do with QTimer. But

`timer->start(0);`

is an issue.
Your video, you input camera has a `frame per second`, which means a period to produce frame. For instance, 25fps means you will get a new frame every time period, `40ms` in this case.

**Short answer:**
Without a proper hardware synchronization, set the timer timeout to `1000 / expected fps`.

**Long answer:**

A timer with `timeout = 0` will schedule a `read_shape_params` as fast as the framework can. which means that the performance bottleneck end up being `capture->read(frame);`, assuming the other part of the code (display, etc..) work perfectly.

There are 3 cases about `capture->read(frame)`:

1. It takes more time that the resolution that time period : You can't do anything. It will be slow.
2. It is exact same time. This is the sweet spot. This is also very unlikely.
3. It takes less time that the resolution that time period : Should be good right? Wrong. You read the same image multiple times. Which means at best you waste cpu resource. At worst, things start to behave like in case 1 from your point of view. How is that? Let say it take 30 ms to present a frame (read and show, I assume you do it linearly).

   ```
   Read 1 : 30 ms, frame 1
   Read 2 : 30 ms, frame 1 // wasted read, the other party has not updated the frame yet
   Read 3 : 30 ms, frame 2 // your second frame has 60 ms latency, not 40 ms
   Read 4 : 30 ms, frame 3 // frame 3 has 120 ms latency, sweet spot.
   Read 5 : 30 ms, frame 3 // wasted read
   Read 6 : 30 ms, frame 4 // frame 3 has 120 ms latency, sweet spot.
   ```

If on top of that you keep queuing item for display, and display is slow, your perceived fps will be lower.

- **You need to benchmark the execution time of
  `video_stream_reader::read_frame` to be sure.**
- **You also need to benchmark whichever code take care of displaying the
  image. I  suspect there is a bottleneck there.**